# CakePHP best practice for widget-like component

Tags: cakephp

I would like to build a widget that can be included in different views as a small box.

The widget is a table that displays some rows from a table (Model) "Xyz"; some of the rows (according to user permissions) are editable (the user can change their value).

What is the best way to implement such a (simple) thing (I'm a newbie with CakePHP)?
In particular:

1. in which file should I put the presentation code (usually a .ctp) in order to allow it to be included in other views?
2. in which file should I put the code for retrieving the data and preparing the variables for the presentation code? Usually it should go to a Controller, but can I include/call a Controller method from another Controller.
3. in which file should I put the code for handling the POST requests?

Comment: If you want to include something in every page include it in default.ctp (in `views/layout` folder) 

You can call other controller function using requestAction method or simply linking that controller and action

Answer (score 3):

Use an element to store the widget markup and use requestAction to fetch the data:

/app/View/Elements/widget.ctp

```
$data = $this->requestAction('/controller/action/param1/etc');

debug($data);
```

If you do it this way (as apposed to putting it in AppController::beforeFilter()), the data will only ever be fetched when the widget it displayed

Comment: Ok, but where can I handle the POST data? (especially in the case when some posted fields are wrong and I need to redisplay the same table with the modified fields and error)

Comment: You could do an Ajax request that always goes to the same controller action. The controller action could respond in json/xml and you could display the results.

Comment: As @jimiyash recommends, Ajax is the way forward here

Comment: @RichardAtHome In cake using `$this->requestAction()` is  discouraged as it invokes full dispatcher, routing and so on. In other words it makes another separate request to application.

Comment: @icebreaker That myth was substantially debunked a long while back :-) http://www.cakedc.com/mark_story/2009/02/27/benchmarking-requestaction (there's was a more thorough debunking article but I can't find it now >.< edit: Actually I think that was the article, but the page colour scheme has changed since I last read it)

Comment: @RichardAtHome Thanks, need to review my old coding habits. :)

Answer (score 0):

Briefly

1. app/Views/Elements/fancy_element.ctp and then include it in app/Views/Layouts/default.ctp
2. app/Controller/AppController.php

   `class AppController extends Controller {`

   ```
   function beforeFilter() {
       parent::beforeFilter();
       $this->set(
           'cool_variable', 
           $this->YourMethodOrComponent->action($params)
         );
   }
   ```

   `}`
3. As your business logic requires. Usually it would be YourFancyController/your_cool_action. Just take care of redirection or refresh in case of ajax request.

---

Edit: RichardAtHome proposed better solution as my assumptions were made based on very outdated principles.